# set multiple Search Params in the same render cycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I use a [Tree](https://mui.com/components/tree-view/) from mui v5 and I want to add in searchParams node that are selected and expanded. To do this I use the hook [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usesearchparams) from React Router (v6).

The fact is that event selected and expanded are firing in the same rendering of the component.

So when the first write params by setSearchParams(...) the second do the same but with the same searchParams and erase params setted by the first.

I made a [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/searchparams-r5tt4) which reproduces the behavior.

I try to use a ref to allow to mutate `freshSearchParams`but I did not succeed.

Comment: The only solution I find, it's use useState on the App component for expanded, selected and set each one, and useEffect to post the both values on the same post (without key of course).

Comment: Work perfectly, but maybe I broke your approach

Comment: I tried this but my implem doesnt works perfectly. The components works but params was not "fresh". I noticed a delay of one iteration to see the right extended param in the url. If yours is ok I'm interested to see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the TreeView component is dispatching both onNodeSelect and onNodeToggle on the same Click. One thing you can do is customize both `handleToggle` and `handleSelect` functions, so they combine the two `expanded` and `selected` variables.

I'd take another approach to this scenario. I'd use a custom hook that handles the Tree state and wraps that state with that searchParams functionality. You can initialize the state from the URL and update the search parameters when the state is updated. I'd implement that URL update with a useEffect that compares status to URL and makes the appropriate updates.

Here's a possible implementation of that custom hook.

```
const useTreeUrlStatus = () => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
    return {
      selected: searchParams.get("selected") ?? "",
      expanded: searchParams.get("expanded")
        ? searchParams.get("expanded").split(",")
        : []
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (
      searchParams.get("selected") !== state.selected ||
      searchParams.get("expanded") !== state.expanded
    ) {
      setSearchParams({
        selected: state.selected,
        expanded: state.expanded.join(",")
      });
    }
  }, [state, searchParams, setSearchParams]);

  const updateState = (key, value) => {
    setState((prevState) => {
      const newState = { ...prevState, [key]: value };
      return newState;
    });
  };

  return [state, updateState];
};
```

You have a [working sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/searchparams-forked-qhtu2) forked from your posted sandbox.